# How Sending files via socket io with nestjs in the event

Tags: node.js, typescript, sockets, nestjs, nestjs-socket.io

How Sending files via socket io with nestjs in the event

How Sending files via socket io with nestjs in the event
How Sending files via socket io with nestjs in the event

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.